# Getting unformatted data from dojo.xhrGet

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jsp, dojo

I have a JSP and a servlet. In the JSP i am giving a ajax call to the servlet. The servlet calls the REST API and gets me data.  So, i get JSON data in the servlet from the REST API. Which i am formatting using,

```
json.serialize(true);
```

The jsondata is formatted. Now, I want to show this json data as it is i.e. in formatted form. So i send it to the frontend.

```
pw.write(myformattedjsontext)
```

where i have the code,

```
var xhrDetailsArgs={    
     handleAs: "text",    
     sync: true,    
     load: function(data)     
     {                  
     document.getElementById("DetailsGrid").innerHTML = data + "";    
     },    
     error: function(error)     
     {    
     alert("Error while loading details"+error);    
     }    
}
```

But i get unformatted data here. The format is lost.I have to get the formatted data here. 
Please Help!!!

Comment: I think if you write handleAs: 'json' you will get a JSON formatted object in the response, or is the problem in your JSP code?

Comment: if i write handle as json then, i will get a json object in my JS. 
How do i print it directly then?

Comment: You can use JSON.stringify(jsonObject), although not all old browsers support that.

Comment: What do you mean printed directly, you get an object ad jan misker said, and you can use the object values to populate what you want. can you be more clear of what you want so we can help you.

Comment: I want to print the json data directly as it is , without compressing it in one line(or without changing its format.). But what happens is, it tries to compress the data. And then the indentation is gone.

Comment: It sounds like you want to pretty-print the response directly into the page somewhere..is that accurate?

Answer (score 1):

If you change your handleAs attribute to "json", you will have an object in your data variable. You can use

`JSON.stringify(data, null, " ");`

to get a formatted json string.